# JavaScript (JQuery) table very slow to load when processing JSON (via PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a fairly simplistic HTML page that relies on JQuery to process a JSON object after a Form has been submitted and then organize the data in a large table (upwards of 1000+ rows depending on the criteria selected in the Form, and 50 columns)

The request goes to a PHP page which does some fairly heavy computations to build the JSON array and send it back to be processed by JQuery. The JS organizes the data in an HTML table.

The number of objects returned in the JSON array varies depending on the settings chosen in the form, but the length of time seems to increase the total load time on the HTML page ***exponentially***. 
I know that each JSON object is fairly large, but I need all of the information that is returned so it's not really an option to pare it down any further.

My problem is that I'm unable to figure out where in my code the slow down is occurring? 
Is it the size of the JSON array?

**What I've Tried:**

- Speeding up the PHP/MYSQL selections (helped minimally)
- Time the PHP script by writing to a *.txt file when the script begins
  and ends. Even in the worst case scenario (most options selected on the HTML form) the total time never exceeds 4-5 seconds to process json_encode.
- Use the ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); prior to the json_encode (didn't
  seem to make any difference).
- I took out the JS Plugins to sort the table columns (originally used sorttable.js and changed to stupidtable to speed things up, but didn't seem to work)
- I tried using Chrome's heap snapshot to identify any memory leaks and
  to find the total size of the JSON array. Honestly, I'm not really
  sure what I'm looking at??

I appreciate any help you can give me. I've spent the last day searching through Google and StackOverflow, but I'm currently at a loss. 
Thank you

Comment: use the dev tools f12 to see how long it is taking the request from the server to come back.  Add some logging in your js after it comes back between different operations to see where the bottleneck might be.  Trying to display 1000k+ table rows in the dom all at once is going to affect performance.  I would consider a JS table api, such as, DataTables that will only show so many table rows at once in the dom.  Something that you could feed the whole json object into to page it.

Comment: I console.logged the time time it took for the JSON to return from the server, and it was only a couple of seconds, but took a minute and a half to create 650 rows in the table. I will take a look at implementing DataTables. Thanks for your help Paul - if you create an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the dev tools f12 to see how long it is taking the request from the server to come back. Add some logging in your js after it comes back between different operations to see where the bottleneck might be. Trying to display 1000k+ table rows in the dom all at once is going to affect performance. I would consider a JS table api, such as, DataTables that will only show so many table rows at once in the dom. Something that you could feed the whole json object into to page it.

https://datatables.net/